# Reactive Form with parent and child routes

Tags: angular, router, angular-reactive-forms

I have a data entry form and I am using a parent/child router to define a parent component that renders some tabs, each tab loads a section of the entity being edited.

For example: I have a component which renders some tabs, each tab routes to a child route and renders part of the model (see routes below)

```
[
  { 
    path: ':id', 
    component: ParentComponent, 
    resolve: {someModel: SomeModelResolver }, 
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'summary', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'summary', component: SummaryComponent },
      { path: 'other', component: OtherComponent },
      ...
    ]
  }
]
```

I am using reactive forms in all child components and I am having some trouble

a) accessing data across all child routes (i think I can do this through the activatedRoute.parent.data), and;

b) validating the data across all child routes since the save/cancel buttons are in the parent route component

Does anyone have any advice on how I can achieve this please? (I would prefer a reactive forms solution rather than template driven forms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach which works really well without using router but DI by passing child formGroups via *@Input* decorators to the child components. Tested this with really huge forms using @angular/material‘s *mat-accordion* and *mat-tab-group*. Performance is quite good and the form gets nicely separated into smaller peaces like you want it to.

Create getter functions for these child formGroups

```js
get childform1() {
  return this.form.get(‘childForm1‘) as FormGroup;
}
```

and then just use

```html
<app-childform [form]=“childform1“></app-childform>
```

In your child

```js
 @Input() form: FormGroup;
```

Then you can save your complete form easily on your parent component and all values will get passed into it nicely.

Comment: This is the approach I have gone with in the end using `mat-tab-group` and lazy loading

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have some sort of "big form" split into smaller, self contained forms spread out across multiple lazy loaded modules/compoents. Your problem is how to gather data from all of small forms. 4 options comes into my mind.

1. Don't to that and keep single form - but I assume you cannot/dont want to do that
2. Pass whole data filled by user so far using routes data (too complicated imho)
3. Use `localStorage` to persist every form
4. Be more Angular - Store partial forms data in shared service.

If you store everything in shared service (that is accessible to every child component/form), your master component will be able to access all forms data trough service and assembly proper request payload (probably).
Option 3 is what I would pick.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be an option to create an @Injectable class (service) which you can then inject into all your components to share data?

In this service you could also have a save button observer and push the event to all components that way.